# Read password from keyboard instead of stdin

Tags: terminal, zsh, input

I have a `zsh` script that prompts for keyboard entry:

```
read -rs 'pw?Password: '
```

This script also needs to read the contents of a file from stdin.  But the `read` command takes the first line of stdin and uses it as input for the password:

```
myscript <<< 'line1\nline2'    # pw == 'line1'
```

Any way to get around this?  I'd prefer a `zsh` or `bash` solution, though I'm open to others too.

(FWIW, `gpg2` does this, so I know it's possible... just don't know how.)

Comment: Read the passwd from`/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal is always accessible through `/dev/tty`, regardless of where standard input has been redirected from.

```
read -rs 'pw?Password: ' </dev/tty
```